# How to deduce two function of many independent random variables is independent?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let:

- $Z_1,\dots , Z_n$ be a random sample from a population with a standard normal distribution.
- $\bar{Z}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nZ_i$
- $S^2_n = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(Z_i-\bar{Z}_n)^2$

Now, I need to determine that:

- $(k-2)S^2_{k-1}$

and

- $\frac{k-1}{k}(Z_k-\bar{Z}_{k-1})^2$

The given solution says:

> 1. $S^2_{k-1}$ and $(Z_k-\bar{Z}_{k-1})^2$ are functions of sets of random variables that are independent of each other.
> 2. Functions of independent variables are also independent, so $(Z_k-\bar{Z}_{k-1})^2 \perp S^2_{k-1}$

I agree with statement 1 because both expressions are functions of some elements in the given random sample, hence, the elements are independent of each other.

It is statement 2 that I don't understand. I am aware of the following result:

If $X,Y$ are independent random variables, then $g(X),h(Y)$ are independent too i.e. functions of independent random variables are independent too.

I am not sure how to apply the above result to this case because the result above seems to me to require that $g,h$ be a function of distinct random variables. But in this case, the random variables $Z_1,\dots , Z_{k-1}$ are common to both of the functions in statement 1, so I am not sure if I can apply the above result or if there are extensions to this result that cover this case.

Lastly, does the argument presented in the solution apply to all kinds of random sample or is it only limited to the case where the random sample comes from a standard normal distribution?

Comment: The result you mention is only demanding that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. The proof of it makes no use of something as: "$X$ and $Y$ are distinct." Btw, "distinct random variables" is somewhat vague. Random variables are functions. $X(\omega)\neq Y(\omega)$ for a single $\omega$ is allready enough to make it distinct functions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So if I understand this correctly, then if $X,Y$ are independent random variables, then $g(X,Y)$ and $h(X,Y)$ are independent random variables too since both are functions of independent random variables and it does not matter that they are functions of the same random variables. Is this right?

Comment: No, I did not mean to say that. The right conclusion is that $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent (as you allready stated in your question). If $Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ are rvs and $X=u(Z_1,\dots,Z_n$ and $Y=v(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ for measurable $u,v$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are independent then you are allowed to conclude that $g(X)=g\circ u(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ and $h(Y)=h\circ v(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ are also independent. Don't feel restricted by the fact that both have the $Z_i$ as arguments.